# Sharing and updating a library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, shared-libraries, updates

The facts:

- I have a library called ***A***.
- I have two projects, **B** and **C**, referencing ***A***.
- When I compile **B** or **C**, they both create a compiled copy of ***A***.

What I want to achieve is to create setup files for both **B** and **C**.
I also want them to use the same dll of ***A***.

So if I install `B 1.0` which has `A 1.0` with it to a machine and then install the `C 1.2` with `A 1.2` with it, I want **B** to use the updated version of ***A***.

How can I do this?
I think saving the dll to a common place with the setup and dynamically loading it with the app but I'm not sure. What is the best practice here? If I'm going to save it to a common place where would that be? Do setup projects that come with Visual Studio allow these kind of operations?

(I use .NET 4.5 on Visual Studio 2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using assembly redirection. Please refer to [Assembly Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You will create dll hell doing this. You should leave them seperated and compile updated versions for each project.

Create a shared references folder with the updated dll.
Make both projects reference the dll of project A from the shared references folder.

Created version numbers for each new build to keep control of your dll's

Comment: So there is a library that does calculations and I have two projects using it. If I update this library and make it 60% faster, I should update both projects separately with the same new version of the library, or it gets too complicated. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes- from personal experience dll hell is created from not knowing if the dll is backwards compatible. Separate compilation will ensure the new dll matches your code. Just updating a dll cause it's the latest version can be disastrous specially when scaled.

Comment: Can't I somehow check whether it is backward compatible?

Comment: Yes by compiling the solution and code testing. Or spending time with a tool like dllspy